# Invoke a shell script in R studio in Ubuntu

Tags: r, shell, ubuntu

I am new to shell scripting in Ubuntu/LINUX. I need to read the all the folders in `/path/raw/hourly/` and read `NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A*.grb`

The way I do this is as follows:

```
startingDir <- "/path/raw/hourly/"
thepattern <- "NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A*\\.grb"
files <- list.files(path = startingDir, pattern=thepattern, recursive=T, full.names=T)
```

Then, I need to invoke this shell script below to iterate all the `"NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A*\\.grb"` files so it will convert to netCDF format.

But, I need some help to link this shell script to invoke in R studio in Ubuntu/LINUX environment in the code above.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in NLDAS_VIC0125_H.A*.grb
do
  cdo -f nc copy "$file" "/file/path/out/${file%.grb}.nc"
done
```

I tried this code below but it does not produce the output.

```
for (f in files) {
  system(paste('#!/bin/bash','cdo -f nc copy', substr(f,10,47), '/file/path/out/${', substr(f,10,43), '%.grb}.nc'))
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are in R, you could script this in R itself. Something like:  `for (f in files) system(paste('cdo -f nc copy ', startingDir , f,   '/file/path/out/${', f, '}.nc'))`

Comment: Thanks but it returns "Bad substitution".